# How do I show a scroll bar in SmartTable of SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

How to bring ScrollBar Option in SAPUI5 SmartTable control?

It is not showing scrollbar by default and columns on right are not able to see.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"! I've adapted your title, but please try to find a more descriptinve one the next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "ScrollContainer" (sap.m.ScrollContainer) Element around the table, would be the easiest. Otherwise use "FixedColumns"-Option of the table, then scrollbar is integrated automatically (fixedColumnCount : int (default: 0) and
fixedRowCount : int (default: 0)

Comment: I Used the ScrollContainer to resolve the issue, the other thing was in IE the ScrollContainer  was taking width of the component it is enclosing, so i have to set the width manually with ScrollContainer.

Comment: yes right, you have to set the width. please accept the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

a SmartTable should do that by default. I think it depends more on where you want the control to show. Did you put it in a view or page?
If you look at the example on [UI5 Explored](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smarttable/code) you can see it's put in a page where scrolling is disabled. Also the VBox has fitContainer set to true. Can you reproduce that example?

Answer (score 0):

No scrollbar in your smartTable setup?
Ensure your smartTable is in  first ;).
That fixed it for me. I had an m.Table in there and set smartTable's tableType property to just Table